Can my Battle Smith Artificer attack twice with his musket?
My artificer is level 5, with 18 INT (+4). He is proficient with firearms, and uses a Musket, which is a martial weapon according to DMG 268, infused with Repeating Shot:

Repeating Shot Item:
A simple or martial weapon with the ammunition property (requires attunement)
This magic weapon grants a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it when it's used to make a ranged attack, and it ignores the loading property if it has it.
If the weapon lacks ammunition, it produces its own, automatically creating one piece of magic ammunition when the wielder makes a ranged attack with it. The ammunition created by the weapon vanishes the instant after it hits or misses a target.

The Battle Ready ability then states:

Battle Ready
Your combat training and your experiments with magic have paid off in two ways:
• You gain proficiency with martial weapons.
• When you attack with a magic weapon, you can use your Intelligence modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity modifier, for the attack and damage rolls.

Also, at level 5, the Battle Smith gains an extra attack. So, because of the infusion, the Musket is a magical item, and the second part of the Battle Ready ability applies. The Repeating Shot also removes the Loading property of the Musket.
Does this mean I can attack twice per turn with a +8 attack modifier (INT + PB + Repeating Shot bonus) and 1d12+5 (INT + Repeating Shot bonus) piercing damage roll ?

Yes, absolutely
You've read everything correctly. You can attack twice with that musket when you take the attack action, have a +8 bonus on the attack roll and deal 1D12+5 piercing damage on a hit.
